# index.js not working in ReactJs cause of error input is a void element tag

Tags: reactjs, children

I'm making a project with Redux and i got this error in my *index.js* saying "*Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`*."

This is my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import store from "./redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>{" "}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is where the error pointed at:

```
7 |     Provider
   8 | } from "react-redux";
   9 | 
> 10 | ReactDOM.render( <
  11 |     React.StrictMode >
  12 |     <
  13 |     Provider store = {
```

Is there anyway for me to fix it? Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: As the error clearly says you have an input element with children like this => `<input>nothing should be here</input>`.

Comment: I don't get what you mean...

Comment: can you share the code where you use `input` elements?